# PHP - MySQL WHERE not work

Tags: php, sql, select, where-clause

When I add this code to my Php file

```
    include "sql_connect.php";
    $query_blog="SELECT * FROM messages";
    $result_blog=mysql_query($query_blog);

    $num_blog=mysql_numrows($result_blog);

    mysql_close();

        $sql_index_menu="0";
        while ($sql_index_menu < $num) {

        $msg_subject=mysql_result($result,$sql_index_menu,"subject");
        $msg_id=mysql_result($result,$sql_index_menu,"id");
        $msg_from=mysql_result($result,$sql_index_menu,"from");
        $msg_to=mysql_result($result,$sql_index_menu,"recipient");
        $msg_text=mysql_result($result,$sql_index_menu,"text");
        $msg_time=mysql_result($result,$sql_index_menu,"time");
        $msg_read=mysql_result($result,$sql_index_menu,"readed");
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="?action=view&id=<?php echo $msg_id; ?>&lang=<?php echo $actLang; ?>"><?php if($msg_read == "0") {echo "<img src='/images/message.gif' width='32' height='32'>";} else {echo "<img src='/images/message.png' width='32' height='32'>";}?> <?php echo $msg_time; ?></a></td><td><a href="?action=view&id=<?php echo $msg_id; ?>&lang=<?php echo $actLang; ?>"><?php echo $msg_subject; ?></a></td><td><a href="?action=view&id=<?php echo $msg_id; ?>&lang=<?php echo $actLang; ?>"><?php echo $msg_from; ?></a></td>
            </tr>


    <?php
$sql_index_menu++;
}
```

everything work BUT, when i add this to $query_blog

```
$query_blog="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipent='$username'";
```

so it won't work..

I tryed to change $username with my name but it still not working.

This code is working, so I copyed it and still nothing...

```
            include "sql_connect.php";
    $query="UPDATE messages
            SET readed='1'
            WHERE id='$id'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    $num=mysql_numrows($result);

    mysql_close();
    include "sql_connect.php";
    $query_blog="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id='$id'";
    $result_blog=mysql_query($query_blog);

    $num_blog=mysql_numrows($result_blog);

    mysql_close();


    $msg_text=mysql_result($result_blog,$sql_index_blog,"text");
    $msg_from=mysql_result($result_blog,$sql_index_blog,"from");
    $msg_subject=mysql_result($result_blog,$sql_index_blog,"subject");
    $msg_time=mysql_result($result_blog,$sql_index_blog,"time");
```

Can you help me?

I disabled login required to page so now you can see the page (sorry for language :D) As you can see, no error
[The website](http://kots.g6.cz/game_messages.php?lang=cs)

Comment: There's a typo - your WHERE clause has `recipent` instead of `recipient`. You need to check the return value from mysql_query, and handle it appropriately - the database will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Are you getting any MySQL specific error messages for the query that is not working ?

Comment: No I dont.. So yeah I type "recipent" and not recipient so yeah. But now I dont know why it wont work with SELECT * FROM messages :D Do you see any other errors?

Comment: Did you look in `mysql_error()`?

Comment: @andrewsi Yes but nothing..

Comment: @TomášAresakMalčánek - could you edit your question to include the code you're currently using, please?

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned there is a typo, you misstyped recipient, anyway - i recommend you to use mysql_error() function to debug you'r code, an example would be:

```
$result=mysql_query($query) or die("<b>error:</b>".mysql_error()."line:".__LINE__);
```

Comment: Do it anywhere you have mysql_query() function.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug a code in PHP is using **echo** or **print_r**.

In this case, you can include echo on $query_blog after setting it and run the result in your mysql IDE (or mysql command line).

```
$query_blog="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipent='$username'";    
echo $query_blog;
```

Also, it's not a good msyql practice using quotes on where because your code will be vulnerable to injections.

Instead, use this:

```
$result = sprintf("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipent='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($username));

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $result
    die($message);
}
```

Comment: So it seems like echo not working... I trying echo $query, echo "test" but nothing... :O

Edit: I write "s" to code and echo work...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get: you echoed the variable $query_blog and you didn't have anything?  Then, include at the top (after <?php ) the following: error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

Comment: Yes, but then I writed "s" to the code and then it was work... I writed error_reporting to the code.. But no errors on the website

Comment: Did you write echo $query or echo $query_blog?  Not sure, but it seems if you are confused with the variable names.

Comment: I renamed $query_blog to $query, then I canll $query

Comment: In this case you must use print_r() or var_dump().  Eg: print_r($username); If it prints an array, then your query won't work unless you use the index for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying a mysql database from php and you want to use php variables in your query you have to escape them, otherwise you are passing the string '$username', not the value that is stored in $username.

Does this work for you?

`$query_blog="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipent='" . $username . "'";

 var_dump($query_blog);`

Comment: if $username is an array, you will also need to pass it an index.

Comment: So no it not working and with '$username' it work with all my other scripts.

Comment: @TomášAresakMalčánek - there's no difference between `"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipent='" . $username . "'"` and `"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recipent='$username'"`. It's the quotes at the start and end of the string that determine with variables are interpolated - a double quoted string that happens to include some single quotes will still interpolate variables.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @andrewsi! I struggled with the syntax for quite a while and I could only make my queries work with the double quote quote dot escape.  I suppose it's because something was wrong somewhere else.